# Value of cosinus 90 degree

Tags: java, math, trigonometry

Using java.lang.Math functions. 
Could someone exaplain why the value of cos(90) = 6.1 ?

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 91; i++) {
        System.out.println(i  + " = " + cos(toRadians(i)));
    }
```

Output is:

```
0 = 1.0
1 = 0.9998476951563913
2 = 0.9993908270190958
...
89 = 0.0174524064372836
90 = 6.123233995736766E-17
```

Comment: You answer is here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5263743/3780625

Comment: It's **not** 6.1, but 0.000000000000000061. Notice the `E-17` after the number.

Comment: Why isn't it 0? Due to floating point precision issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please note the exponential notation. The output

```
90 = 6.123233995736766E-17
```

does not indicate a value of `6.1`, but a value of `6.1*10^{-17}`.

Which is close to **zero** (`0`). It is not absolute zero because of precision issues with floating points.